# Error in compiling libsmtp (glib-config not found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, smtplib

I am trying to install [libsmtp](http://libsmtp.berlios.de/) on Ubuntu 12.04, and upon compiling i am getting errors, here's the step i followed (they are exactly the same as written in Install.txt file)

```
cd libsmtp
./configure
```

[The output of above command is]

```
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for main in -lglib... no
checking for main in -lglib... (cached) no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
```

The list goes on, but remaining dependencies are installed.
From the output it can be seen that its not able to find 'lglib', but its actually installed, the output of modversion is:

```
usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/smtp/libsmtp-0.8.5$ pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
2.32.3
```

And due to this i got error on running 'make', here's the output:

```
usama@ubuntu:~/Desktop/smtp/libsmtp-0.8.5$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/smtp/libsmtp-0.8.5/smtp'
gcc -I. -I../include `glib-config --cflags` -g -O2 -DUSE_MIME   -c -o    libsmtp_comm.o libsmtp_comm.c
/bin/sh: 1: glib-config: not found
libsmtp_comm.c:28:20: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [libsmtp_comm.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/smtp/libsmtp-0.8.5/smtp'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can anyone please tell how to resolve this issue ?

**Updated:**

The portion of configure script dealing with glib is :

```
 echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
 (exit $ac_status); }; }; then
 ac_cv_lib_glib_main=yes
 else
 echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
 sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

 ac_cv_lib_glib_main=no
 fi
 rm -f conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext \
   conftest$ac_exeext conftest.$ac_ext
 LIBS=$ac_check_lib_save_LIBS
fi
echo "$as_me:$LINENO: result: $ac_cv_lib_glib_main" >&5
echo "${ECHO_T}$ac_cv_lib_glib_main" >&6
if test $ac_cv_lib_glib_main = yes; then
cat >>confdefs.h <<_ACEOF
#define HAVE_LIBGLIB 1
_ACEOF
```

LIBS="-lglib $LIBS"

```
echo "$as_me:$LINENO: checking for main in -lglib" >&5
echo $ECHO_N "checking for main in -lglib... $ECHO_C" >&6
if test "${ac_cv_lib_glib_main+set}" = set; then
echo $ECHO_N "(cached) $ECHO_C" >&6
else
 ac_check_lib_save_LIBS=$LIBS
LIBS="-lglib  $LIBS"
```

Comment: Glib is weird! You have to tell the compiler to use Glib's very own include path (should be in /usr/include/glib-2.0 or sth like that).

Comment: Hm, and how can i do that ? [If u can please tell the exact command ?] and yes its in the /usr/include/glib-2.0 .

Comment: ./configure [... etc ...] CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/glib-2.0' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include/glib-2.0'

Comment: upon writing this command 'pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0' i got this output: '-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0'     i gave the CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to ./configure like this,  ./configure CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/glib-2.0' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include' but still its not able to find glib :/

Comment: That's probably because the configure script of libsmtp is weird, too: it has `glib-config` hardcoded. You may put that `pkg-config ...` in a script named `glib-config`, make it accessible from PATH and try again

Comment: fork0, i have included the portion of configure script dealing with glib, can u tell how do i make changes in the configure script ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i am able to get rid of glib error, here are the steps u need to follow:

First make sure that libgtk2.0 is installed on your system, if its not installed then u can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Tell the compiler the path of glib-2.0, the exact command is written below:
( **Note:** The path of libgtk may differ in your system, to check the path use the following command:)

```
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
```

U should get an output similar to that:

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

Now install the libsmtp (or your desired application).

```
cd libsmtp
./configure
make CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/glib-2.0' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include'
```

If you are lucky then u would be able to install your desired application.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```